# How to identify visitors are unique?

Tags: security, anti-cheat

i trying make an internet voting service but the problem is internet is just so easy to cheat by creating multiple accounts and vote same thing. capcha and email is not helping as take just 3 second to pass by human. IP can be changed by proxy. if we put some cookie on voter browser he just clean it next time.

i created this question to ask help for methods we can use with basic futures that all browsers have (javascript etc)to prevent our service being cheated easily.

the first idea i have myself is that possible my website access all cookies user have on his browser by just visiting my site ? because when they clean everything by CCleaner for new accounts then i can understand the browser is empty so the person is perhaps a cheater as most of real users when come to my site always have at least several cookie from different sites

Comment: people can turn off their cookies alltogether (like I do, I only enable them for certain websites), which would make them a 'cheater' in your scenario even though they're just visiting your website

Comment: fortunately, websites only have access to their own cookies. It would be a big security and privacy concern if a website had access to **all* the cookies on a browser

Comment: This problem won't be solved in any way, except for a trusted third party who does actual identification (i.e. log in using oAuth with government ID or something). Anything else can be spoofed (and will be if your poll is important enough). For a practical second, I would say require a facebook login, although even those can be spoofed (and not everyone has facebook), but at least Facebook is then helping you fight the spoofing.

Comment: @Eonasdan but we hear a lot about this advertising companies or facebook that do tracking stuff, so is that all lie ?

Comment: ad companies place a drop a cookie on your computer w/e you visit a site. There is some cross-site stuff that can be setup but there is a process between them. the ads still can't access **all** of the cookies

Comment: @Eonasdan i exactly want that stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to address the issue of uniquely identifying real-world assets (here: humans) without stepping out of your virtual system, *by definition*.**

There are various ways to ensure a higher reliability of the mapping "*one human to exactly one virtual identity*", but none of them is fool-proof.

- The most accessible way would be to do it via a **smartphone** app. A human usually only has one smartphone (and a phone number).
- Another way is to send them snail mail to their **real address**, with a secret code, which you require them to enter in your virtual system.
- or the **social insurance number**
- or their **fingerprints** as log in credentials

The list could go on, but the point is, these things are bound to the **physical world**. If you **combine** more such elements, you get a higher accuracy (but never 100% certainty).

Comment: i looking for a full list of all scripts that possible help us

Comment: Not all problems are "scriptable". Yeah, programming is to a great degree virtual, BUT in the end you deal with problems from the real world. Real-world solutions to real-world problems are thus acceptable.

Comment: To put "*There is no way to address the issue of uniquely identifying real-world assets (here: humans) without stepping out of your virtual system, by definition*" in other way, you can think like this: **if you want to get real (data), you have to get real (data).** No matter how stupid and self-obvious it sounds, it's the core idea.